# Unable to create soap web service client from paypal wsdl in eclipse

Tags: java, web-services, soap, paypal, wsdl

I am trying to create a sop web service client using provided paypal wsdl  [paypal soap architecture](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/PayPalSOAPAPIArchitecture/).

I am trying to create soap web service client in 2 ways:

1. Create a simple web service client(`by option web service client Eclipse`)
2. create web service client using `axis generator` plugin

Using first way ,I am getting error as 'Could not retrieve the WSDL url'.

Using second way I am getting exception as

> wsdlexception faultcode other_error
>
> FileNotFoundException,unable to get eBLBaseComponents xsd file from wsdl .

I have created web service client using first way number of times.

Can anybody guide me in this context? Is there issue with wsdl file?

Thanks,